# How to show two links one by one?

Tags: php, session, cookies, logic

This code below will first show link A and then link B.

The cookie is saved on user pc, if user refresh again and again he will be looking at different link, but what if he clicks and leaves and other user clicks and leave the page, according to this code user is looking at first link always on first click.

What if I use session instead of cookie? Session will be saved on server and both links will be distributed by different users. Or give me alternate of this logic?

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["lastLink"])){
    setcookie("lastLink","b"); // you can set an expire time.
}

if($_COOKIE["lastLink"] == "a"){
    $link = "www.b.com";
    setcookie("lastLink","b");
}elseif($_COOKIE["lastLink"] == "b"){
    $link = "www.a.com";
    setcookie("lastLink","a");
}



echo $link;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DİKKAT! MySQL is deprecated, use MySQLi instead.**

If you use a DB to store links, you can use this:

(I didn't try it because I dont have a DB table, pls try and feedback me)

```
<?php

    $resource = mysql_query($query); // mysql query
    $i = 0; // loop value
    $links = array(); // links container
    while( $values = mysql_fetch_array($resource) )
    {
        $links[$i] = $values["link_column"];
        $i++;
    }

    // What if it is users first visit?
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["lastLink"])){
        // we dont know how many links will be in the DB. also, be aware that indexes start with zero.
        setcookie("lastLink",count($links)); 
    }

    $cookie = $_COOKIE["lastLink"]; // I'm a lazy programmer, sorry

    // we pass the value of cookie and the array of links here, bcz it can be a problem.
    echo gimme_the_link($cookie,$links); 

    // Iterate the cookie value to the next link
    $cookie = ($cookie!=count($links)) ? $cookie+1 : 0;
    setcookie("lastLink",$cookie);

    function gimme_the_link($cookie,$links){
        $return = ($cookie!=count($links)) ? $links[$cookie+1] : $links[0];
        return $return;
    }
?>
```

Comment: When I put two links in database, on first attempt it shows the link on second attempt it shows the second link but on third attempt it show this error "Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\changelink.php on line 30"

Comment: Dump the `$links` array to the screen, to check the third row is in the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

Set an expire time to `setcookie()`, so it will reset the cookie.

Comment: Lets say I save 3 links in a database and i want to show these links one by one repeatedly, what should i use then?

Comment: Well just change first if statement (which line the comment "you can set expire time" lays) `setcookie("lastLink","b")` to `setcookie("lastLink","c")`. Then add third else if. `elseif($_COOKIE["lastLink"] == "c")` . Also be aware that in the second case link must be c.com and cookie must be set to c, and in the third statement link a.com and cookie to a.

Comment: Now it will be dynamic script, Sometimes there will one link sometime two sometime 3 sometime 4, and all links will be saved in database. Then what should I do?

Comment: You must make a new alghoritm with switch case i think. It will be suitable for you.

Comment: Will you please help me in making such algorithm I am very confused.

Comment: Sorry! I am confuse and can't make question of it.
It will be great if u answer here.

Comment: How can I help you if i don't know the situation?

Comment: The situation is that I have few links in database and I want to show them one by one.
EG I have 4 links in database and I want to show them one by one after every refresh.

Comment: Use switch case statement, in every step iterate the value which is controlled every step, and iterate the link value. First, using while loop, create a variable, actually an array, then iterate it's offset in every step.

Comment: Use the other answer.